# Torch 2 installed - Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libnvrtc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: unix, pip, pytorch

I have installed Torch 2 via this command on RunPod io instance

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

Everything installed perfectly fine

With Torch 1 and Cuda 11.7, I was not getting any error but with Torch 2 the below error produced

```
Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libnvrtc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to fix?

It is using unix

On Windows same prodecure working very well

Using Automatic1111 web UI to use Stable Diffusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the cuda libraries packaged with Torch 2. Specifically, the libnvrtc.so library is missing from the latest Torch distribution.

To fix this, I did the following:

1. Download the relevant CUDA libraries. I used CUDA 11.8, by running: "wget [https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run"](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda_11.8.0_520.61.05_linux.run%22)
2. Install the CUDA libraries by running the installer. Deselect the option to install the drivers when presented, as this is not needed. In my case the CUDA libraries are now installed in /usr/local/cuda/lib64
3. Add the path to the CUDA library to you LD_LIBRARY_PATH, by adding "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to your .bashrc file.

This solved the problem for me, but does mean that my system is now bypassing the CUDA libraries that were installed with Pytorch 2 and only using the CUDA libraries I installed.

Presumably this issue will be fixed with subsequent releases of the compiled Pytorch 2 library.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope they fix this ASAP. So how do I run the installer via cmd and where do I find.  .bashrc file. The Unix instance we are using don't have user interface. Only cmd

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score -1):

As already stated by @Theo, it seems to be an issue related with Torch 2. But instead of installing all CUDA libraries on the system level, I just downgraded torch in the virtual environment to 1.13 to solve it.

`pip uninstall torch torchvision`

and the reinstall the version 1.13.1:

`pip install torch==1.13.1 torchvision`